# AWS Systems Manager get inventory is not returing everything?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ssm

I am running a query against our environment using the AWS CLI. My query does not return everything that is listed in the Systems Manager console.

I have compared the output of the above command with what is listed in the Systems Manager console. Some stuff is definitely missing.

```
aws ssm get-inventory --query 'Entities[].Data[]."AWS:InstanceInformation"[].Content[].[ComputerName, IpAddress, PlatformName]'
```

My expected results were to get a list of everything that the Systems Manager console shows in inventory.